# вылеты драйверов на Linux

Tags: linux, драйвер

я хочу перейти на линукс, но есть одна проблема. и на линуксе и на винде у меня постоянно вылетают драйвера. на винде я пофиксил это каким то батником, а на линуксе я так и не понял как это пофиксить. может есть аналог данного фикса на линукс?

вот нужный фрагмент кода с этого батника:

```
::AMD
echo %AMDOF% | find "N/A" >nul && call :HoneCtrlError "You don't have an AMD GPU" && goto Tweaks
::AMD Registry Location
for /f %%i in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}" /s /v "DriverDesc"^| findstr "HKEY AMD ATI"') do if /i "%%i" neq "DriverDesc" (set "REGPATH_AMD=%%i")
::AMD Tweaks
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "3D_Refresh_Rate_Override_DEF" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "3to2Pulldown_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AAF_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "Adaptive De-interlacing" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowRSOverlay" /t Reg_SZ /d "false" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSkins" /t Reg_SZ /d "false" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSnapshot" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSubscription" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AntiAlias_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AreaAniso_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "ASTT_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AutoColorDepthReduction_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableSAMUPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableUVDPowerGatingDynamic" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableVCEPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableAspmL0s" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableAspmL1" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_DeLagEnabled" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_FRTEnabled" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableDMACopy" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableBlockWrite" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "StutterMode" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "PP_SclkDeepSleepDisable" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "PP_ThermalAutoThrottlingEnable" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableDrmdmaPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_EnableComputePreemption" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Main3D_DEF" /t Reg_SZ /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Main3D" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "FlipQueueSize" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "ShaderCache" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Tessellation_OPTION" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Tessellation" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "VSyncControl" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3000" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "TFQ" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\DAL2_DATA__2_0\DisplayPath_4\EDID_D109_78E9\Option" /v "ProtectionControl" /t Reg_BINARY /d "0100000001000000" /f >nul 2>&1
goto Tweaks
```

логи(journalctl --utc -p 4):

```
Nov 17 16:57:52 X99 kernel: EDAC sbridge: CPU SrcID #0, Ha #0, Channel #1 has DIMMs, but ECC is disabled
Nov 17 16:57:52 X99 kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
Nov 17 16:57:52 X99 kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
Nov 17 16:57:52 X99 kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-UiLXaH/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c>
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: index 48 is out of range for type 'UCHAR [1]'
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-UiLXaH/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c>
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: index 1 is out of range for type 'UCHAR [1]'
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-UiLXaH/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c>
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: index 2 is out of range for type 'ATOM_PPLIB_NONCLOCK_INFO [1]'
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-UiLXaH/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/si_dpm.c:6831:39
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: index 2 is out of range for type 'ATOM_PPLIB_NONCLOCK_INFO [1]'
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: ================================================================================
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-UiLXaH/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/si_dpm.c:6868:32
Nov 17 16:57:54 X99 kernel: index 16 is out of range for type 'UCHAR [1]'
```

P.S.
я смотрел на логи с конца и вот что я увидел:

```
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:02.0
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:   device [8086:6f04] error status/mask=00001100/00002000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [ 8] Rollover              
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [12] Timeout               
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER:   Error of this Agent is reported first
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0:   device [1002:683f] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0:    [ 6] BadTLP                
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1:   device [1002:aab0] error status/mask=000010c0/00002000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1:    [ 6] BadTLP                
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1:    [12] Timeout               
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:02.0
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:   device [8086:6f04] error status/mask=00004000/00000000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [14] CmpltTO                (First)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: device recovery failed
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:02.0
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:   device [8086:6f04] error status/mask=00004000/00000000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [14] CmpltTO                (First)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: device recovery failed
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: Multiple Uncorrected (Fatal) error received: 0000:00:02.0
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:   device [8086:6f04] error status/mask=00004020/00000000
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [ 5] SDES                  
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0:    [14] CmpltTO                (First)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: Root Port link has been reset (0)
Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.0: AER: device recovery failed
Nov 18 14:35:00 X99 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 37 callbacks suppressed
```

а именно вот эта строчка

`Nov 18 14:34:59 X99 kernel: radeon 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)`

я посмотрел об этом на форумах, но там у людей такая ошибка на виртуальной машине,а у меня на реальном железе.

вывод команды neofetch(вдруг нужна будет информация о системе):

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               int@X99 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: X99 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.6.1-1-liquorix-amd64 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 8 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1672 (dpkg), 11 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.15 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1600x900 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 45.0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-purple-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-purple [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4 (24) @ 2. 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1891MiB / 15839MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

UPD: похоже нашел решение проблемы.Сменил драйвера с radeon на amdgpu и все пока что работает нормально(хотя бы не вылетает через 2 минуты нагрузки)

Comment: Что такое «вылетают драйвера»?

Comment: @andreymal в прямом смысле вылетают драйвера. на винде вылазит сообщение о том что драйвер прекратил свою работу и был перезапущен, а на линуксе просто пропадает изображение(если на фоне музыка то она не пропадает) и как я понял вылетает x11

Comment: Это намекает на то, что у вас неисправная видеокарта и вам нужно её чинить или менять

Comment: @andreymal но как она тогда исправно работает на винде после применения батника?

Comment: Видимо из-за того, что он помогает обойти какую-то аппаратную проблему на программном уровне (но из-за того, что вы не пытаетесь разобраться, что конкретно делает этот батник и какая конкретно строчка решает проблему - трудно сказать что конкретно происходит)

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю что мне нужно разбираться, но у меня не выдавалось свободного времени, сейчас есть свободное время поэтому буду разбираться

Comment: Если вы не хотите чинить/менять видеокарту, то остаётся только предложить читать документацию к используемому вами драйверу и перебирать все подряд опции, доступные в нём, в надежде на то, что они что-нибудь поменяют как этот батник

Comment: вместо всего этого лучше бы привели журнал с ошибкой, [Использование journalctl для просмотра и анализа логов: подробный гайд](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/533918/)

Comment: @andreymal в данный момент я на винде сижу, линукса у меня нету(пока что)

Comment: Если погуглить текст ошибки, то можно нагуглить [что-то такое](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c63079c61177ba1b17fa05c6875699a36924fe39), в связи с чем можно понадеяться, что вылет исправится когда выйдет следующая версия линукса

Comment: Ну и конкретно про Ubuntu тут (можно понадеяться что бэкпортируют фикс) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2037762

Comment: Стоило бы написать, что за видео карта, какие драйвера на нее стоят, откуда этот батник.

Comment: @andreymal только что определил - эта ошибка появляется только при запуске системы. похоже драйвер вылетает без ошибки, или он не логирует ошибку

Comment: @user7860670 видеокарта - amd radeon hd 7750, драйвера для линукс - mesa-vulkan-drivers , часть кода батника взята из Hone Control Panel